# Complex binding expression with IF on asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a repeater with a column that I needs to have the following expression, but not sure of the syntax.

If value="DispForm.aspx"  then
   Show "No Document"
Else
  Show the real value.

I tried to use all expresion in one line, but not sure what am I missing here

```
 <a href=" <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Path") %>">
                         <%#
                             if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName") == "DispForm.aspx")
                             {
                                 "No document";
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName");}%>
                     </a>
```

Error :

http://screencast.com/t/ZERZjzZxST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it my self like this: item databound events will be fired on the server side for each row, and this report returns 2000 rows. Not a good thing.

```
   <a href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fileNameUrl") %>">
                             <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName").ToString() == "DispForm.aspx" ? "No document" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName").ToString() %>
                         </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to use the ItemDataBound event, add an id and runat="server" to the anchor element, then you can use e.Item.FindControl("anchorname") to get the htmlanchor element. You can then set it's text, href, visibility etc. in codebehind far easier than trying to get some of the more difficult databinding logic to work effectively.

Comment: I dont agree, item data bound is fired for each row, and the report is worth 2000 rows.

Comment: Of course it's called on each row. Your DataBinder.Eval is evaluated on each and every row as well as any markup in the ItemTemplate. You may even get a boost performance-wise because the codebehind will be slightly better optimized at compile-time compared to the inline markup.

Comment: maybe I am missing something here, the datatable is in memory, and the databinder.eval just evaluates an expression based on datacolumns already in memory.  Howevre a server side databound event is fired for each row, so it has to go to the server for each row, in my opinion the databinder.eval already has the datatable in memory and should be faster.?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the datatable is stored as it's always a variable in memory. You have an itemtemplate which has DataBinder.Eval being performed on it. It's not running this once, it must run it for each and every item in the datasource. There is no way for it to do it a single time as the DataBinder.Eval is called on each record in the datasource as it has to evaluate each field. That is why you are passing Container.DataItem to the Eval method. That Container.DataItem only represents the current item it is binding to. Not all at once. There is no performance gain doing it this way.